How to display an image with classes in tkinter?
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("300x300")
canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width=300, height=300,bg="red")
canvas.pack()

class Button():
    def __init__(self, x, y, canv):
        self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Hover.png"))
        canv.create_image(x, y, image=self.img, anchor="nw")

Button(0, 0, canvas)

window.mainloop()

I am trying to display an image in python using the tkinter canvas option. However, if I input it in a class, like below, it doesn't give an error but also doesn't show my image.
Pls solve this for me without put the canvas inside of the class

You need to keep a reference of the instance of the class to avoid garbage collection, like img1 = Button(...).


Make sure the image path is correct.

Add self.canv = canv to the __init__:


import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


class Button:
    def __init__(self, x, y, canv):
        self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Hover.png"))
        self.canv = canv
        self.canv.create_image(x, y, image=self.img, anchor="nw")
        self.canv.image = self.img

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("300x300")
canv = tk.Canvas(window, width=300, height=300, bg="red")
canv.pack()

Button(0, 0, canv)

window.mainloop()


Style
You can also style it by setting positions and scale:
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


class Button:
    def __init__(self, x, y, canv, img_path, scale=100):
        self.canv = canv
        self.img_path = img_path
        self.scale = scale / 100.0
        self.set_scale()
        self.border = self.canv.create_rectangle(
            x - 5,
            y - 5,
            x + self.img.width() + 5,
            y + self.img.height() + 5,
            outline="white", width=5)

        self.img_id = self.canv.create_image(x, y, image=self.img, anchor="nw")

        self.canv.tag_bind(self.img_id, "<Enter>", self.hover)
        self.canv.tag_bind(self.img_id, "<Leave>", self.unhover)

    def set_scale(self):
        orig = Image.open(self.img_path)
        w, h = orig.size
        sw, sh = int(w * self.scale), int(h * self.scale)
        resized = orig.resize((sw, sh), Image.LANCZOS)
        self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized)

    def set_pos(self, x, y):
        self.canv.coords(self.img_id, x, y)
        self.canv.coords(self.border, x - 5, y - 5, x + self.img.width() + 5, y + self.img.height() + 5)

    def hover(self, event):
        self.canv.itemconfig(self.border, outline="yellow")

    def unhover(self, event):
        self.canv.itemconfig(self.border, outline="white")


window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("300x300")
canv = tk.Canvas(window, width=300, height=300, bg="red")
canv.pack()

button = Button(0, 0, canv, "hover.png", 30)
button.set_pos(25, 25)

window.mainloop()



Since there is no variable referencing the class instance, the class instance will be garbage collected and so to the image created inside the class instance.
Simply keep references to the class instances:
img1 = Button(0, 0, canvas)
img2 = Button(50, 50, canvas)



I am trying to display an image in python using the tkinter canvas
option. However, if I input it in a class, like below, it doesn't give
an error but also doesn't show my image

The problem can be fixed.
Just add line 13.
canv.image = self.img

Snippet:
class Button():
    def __init__(self, x, y, canv):
        self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Hover.png"))
        canv.create_image(x, y, image=self.img, anchor="nw")
        canv.image = self.img

Screenshot:

